# Bring gvim forward when I open a new tab from the command line

Tags: command-line, window-manager

I like my vi command to open the file in Gvim and to open it in a new tab if Gvim is already running.

```
function vi {
    if [[ -z $@ ]]; then
        gvim 
    elif [[ ${1:0:1} = - ]]; then
        gvim "$@"
    else
        gvim --remote-tab-silent "$@"
    fi
}
```

This works, but when I specify a filename and it opens in an existing Gvim instance, it doesn't bring the window to the front like it does on Mac or Windows.

How can I make it so that when I enter a "vi file.txt" command in the terminal, it will make Gvim the active window?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit dirty, it can be done using `xdotool`.

Add this to your script :

```
    xdotool windowfocus `xdotool search --name "/* - GVIM"` && xdotool windowraise `xdotool search --name "/* - GVIM"`
```

It search a window named "[Something] - GVIM" and raising it. Maybe, you can select the window with more specific title using filename and regex for example.

```
    xdotool windowfocus `xdotool search --name "^$filename\s\+\s\(~\)\s-\sGVIM"` && xdotool windowraise `xdotool search --name "^$filename\s\+\s\(~\)\s-\sGVIM"`
```

But, `xdotool` is must be downloaded first from `apt-get`. Type `sudo apt-get install xdotool` on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I use xdotool too. Such a simple script helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
gvim -p --remote-tab $@ ; xdotool search --name "/* - GVIM" windowactivate
```